# freezes and hangs in macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro

i have a 2009 macbook pro. it has been working fine till now. since the past 2 weeks when i open an application or browse the net it freezes. i see a message saying waiting for cache or waiting for Appcache. this happens almost every 5 minutes.

any ideas on how i can stop this and get my macbook back to normal?

can third party apps like mackeeper resolve this? anyone out there with a similar issue that has used it?

Comment: what os x are you using?

Comment: There are 2 tools on your Mac you can use to find the source. The Activity monitor, and the Console. Both are in your utility folder. Open and look what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Is the waiting for cache message showing up in Google Chrome? If that is the case, then yes, that's a pretty common issue with Chrome itself not specific to OS X. I've had that issue a number of times and have yet to find any way to resolve it apart from a full wipe of the application.

As for the other applications you are talking about, are there some specific applications that freeze, or all apps in general? A screenshot of your Activity Monitor would be ver helpful.

Comment: This belongs in the comment section not as a answer.